# Finding the largest value and the smallest in my code in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, max, minimum

I am creating a code that is to let the user type in the temperature of different sort.

The user should be able to type in:

Amount of weeks
How many time the person is measuring the temperature in one week.
The temperatures for every week.

When the user has typed the information, the program should show the temperatures that have been typed in.

The program should show the lowest temperature every week.
The program should show the highest temperature every week.
The program should show lowest, and highest temperature during all the weeks.
The program should show the average temperature during every week, and during all the weeks.

This is how far i've come:

```
{
    System.out.println ("Temperatures\n");


    Scanner    in = new Scanner (System.in);
    in.useLocale (Locale.US);

    //Here is where information is being put in
    System.out.print ("amount of weeks: ");
    int    amountOfWeeks = in.nextInt ();
    System.out.print ("measuring temperature per week: ");
    int    measurementsPerWeek = in.nextInt ();

    //array to store the information
    double[][]    t = new double[amountOfWeeks + 1][measurementsPerWeek + 1];

    //mata in temperaturerna
    for (int week = 1; week <= amountOfWeeks; week++)
    {
        System.out.println ("temperatures - week " + week + ":");
        for (int measurement = 1; measurement <= measurementsPerWeek; measurement++)
            t[week][measurement] = in.nextDouble ();
    }
    System.out.println ();

    //show the temperatures
    System.out.println ("temperatures");
    for (int week = 1; week <= amountOfWeeks; week++)
    {
        for (int measurement = 1; measurement <= measurementsPerWeek; measurement++)
            System.out.print (t[week][measurement] + " ");

        System.out.println ();
        }

    //lowest, highest, the sum of all temperatures, and average temp per week
    double[]    minT = new double[amountOfWeeks + 1];
    double[]    maxT = new double[amountOfWeeks + 1];
    double[]    sumT = new double[amountOfWeeks + 1];
    double[]    averageT = new double[amountOfWeeks];

    // write the code to find the lowest temperature for the first week



    //´Lowest, highest, sum, average for all weeks
    double    minTemp = minT[1];
    double    maxTemp = maxT[1];
    double    sumTemp = sumT[1];
    double    averageTemp = 0;


}
```

}

Comment: import java.util.*;    //Scanner, Locale

class Temperatures
{
 public static void main (String[] args)                                    should be in the beginning of the code

Comment: Specifically i just need some help to get started on how to find the minimum temperature in my code.

Comment: You could take a look at `DoubleSummaryStatistics`.

Answer (score 0):

The general algorithm to find the maximum value in a list is to iterate through the list and store the maximum value encountered so far.  For example, if you have 10 numbers stored in an array of ints:

```
int max=intArray[0];
for (int i=1; i<10;i++)
         if (intArray[i]>max)
             max=intArrray[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the array into a stream and use the min() method [or max(), or average()] to get an OptionalDouble value.

```
OptionalDouble minValue = Arrays.stream(myArray).min();
```

Then, if you just want to print it, use ifPresent() with a lambda expression or a method reference:

```
minValue.ifPresent(e -> System.out.println(e));

minValue.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

or if you want to do something else, you can use the get() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare:

```
double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
```

and whenever you read a temperature you test if it's a new max or min and update them if necessary like this:

```
...
t[week][measurement] = in.nextDouble ();
if (t[week][measurement] < min) min = t[week][measurement];
if (t[week][measurement] > max) max = t[week][measurement];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I now reviewed the answers posted here and wrote this in to my code:

```
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

for (int week = 1; week<= amountOfWeeks ; week++)
{
    for (int measurement = 1; measurement <= measurementsPerWeek; measurement ++)
         if (t[week][measurement] < min)
         min = t[week][measurement];

         System.out.println ("min is:" + min);
     }
```

Now the code goes through the input data for all of the inputs for all the weeks, and finds the minimum number and prints it. So basically, if the first temperature in the first week is 1, and the user doesn't type any lower than 1, my code will put this number as the minimum for all the weeks.

How can i change this so that it also finds the minimum input for each and every week for itself?